# Grouping issue statuses for YouTrack Agile Board columns

Tags: youtrack

Did anyone find a way to create "overview" agile boards, which would map several issue statuses into the same column on the board?

Our workflow is quite complicated, to be able to track stages of spec / development / QA / customer interaction, yet for overall project reporting seeing all those columns on the board is quite confusing. So far I couldn't find a simple way to create "grouped" columns.

One method I can think of is create another issue field (akin to general status), and re-assign it with every status change. Yet I wonder if there may be a simpler approach (perhaps involving export to an external Kanban-type tool?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Here's the respective feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-23023.